# Ultrafilter Proof of the Compactness theorem

Tags: compactness, model-theory

In David Marker's *Model Theory: An Introduction*, Exercise 2.5.20, he gives the ultrafilter/ultraproduct based proof of the Compactness theorem. I am concerned with a small detail of the proof.

[image]

Is there a small error in part (a)?
Technically, a set $Y$ is in $D$ if and only if $Y$ extends $X_\phi$ for some $\mathcal{L}$-sentence $\phi$. So all $Y$ have some $X_\phi$ as a subset - where $X_\phi$ is the whole set of all finite theories containing $\phi$.
By my reasoning, then, every $Y \in D$ must, for some $\phi$, contain all finite theories $\Delta$ that contain $\phi$.

So, choose $A$ and $B$ in $D$; then for some $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$,
\begin{equation}
X_{\phi_1} \subset A \subset I
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
X_{\phi_2} \subset B \subset I
\end{equation}
So the intersection of $A$ and $B$ must contain $X_\psi$ for some $\psi$, but why is $A \cap B$ guaranteed to contain this, and what would $\psi$ be? I was thinking of $\psi = \phi_1 \land \phi_2$ because $A \cap B$ contains every finite theory that contains both $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$, but just because a theory contains $\phi_1$ and $\phi_2$ doesn't mean it contains $\phi_1 \land \phi_2$, because there's nothing mentioned about taking logical completion and that doesn't make sense in this context. The proof on ProofWiki is slightly different than this one so I was wondering if this was a bug.

Comment: I think the picture is unrelated to the question. Do you want to correct it?

Comment: LOL thanks. That's what happens when you save all your screenshots in a "misc" folder with random alphanumeric strings as titles.

Comment: The proof I know is also a bit different, in that you consider $X_{\{\phi_1,..., \phi_n\}}$ with obvious notations, so that $X_{\{\phi_1,...,\phi_n\}}\cap X_{\{\psi_1,...,\psi_n\}} = X_{\{\phi_1,...,\phi_n, \psi_1,...,\psi_n\}}$, and thus it works fine

Comment: Yeah that's what the proof on ProofWiki looks like that I mention at the end.

Comment: Marker's book is not known for its *lack* of typos. I think you're right that the proof doesn't work as stated and should be amended as suggested by @Max, or by first adding to the theory each sentence which is a consequence of a finite subset.

Comment: If T is satisfiable then WLOG we can assume that T is closed under finite conjunctions, although apparently the author forgot to state this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're right. Interestingly, Marker has in his [the errata](http://homepages.math.uic.edu/~marker/mt-errors.html) that in the rest of the exercise you're supposed to work with the filter *generated by* $D$. So, as noted by Alex Kruckman, you just need to show that $D$ has the finite intersection property, which is not very difficult: in the case of the op, $A \cap B$ is not empty, since it contains $\{\phi_1, \phi_2\}$. As noted by Alex in his comments, this clearly generalizes for every finite intersection.

Comment: I don't think $D$ is a filter basis. The intersection of $X_{\phi_1}$ and $X_{\phi_2}$ does not contain anything of the form $X_\phi$ since every element of it have at least two elements.

Comment: @Idéophage - Yes, yes, I read the op's a bit too hastily; when he said "the intersection of $A$ and $B$ must contain...", I thought that was a conclusion! I'm going to edit the answer soon.

Comment: Marker's errata is correct: $D$ is not a [filter basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_(mathematics)#Filter_on_a_set), but Marker doesn't claim it is. He says "work with the filter generated by $D$", meaning that we have to close $D$ under finite intersections. Any set with the finite intersection property (any intersection of finitely many elements is nonempty) generates a proper filter in this way. And if $Y_1,\dots,Y_n\in D$, witnessed by $X_{\varphi_i}\subseteq Y_i$ for all $1\leq i\leq n$, then $Y_1\cap \dots\cap Y_n$ is nonempty, since it contains $\{\varphi_1,\dots,\varphi_n\}$.

Comment: @AlexKruckman - So another patch would be to first throw $Y_1 \cap \dots \cap Y_n$ into $D$ to get $D'$ and *then* generating a filter?

Comment: @AlexKruckman - Anyway, so although $D$ is not a filter basis, my original claim that it sufficed to prove that $D$ had the f.i.p. was correct?

Comment: Right. To form the filter generated by a family of sets, you close under finite intersections, then close upward. A family of sets is a filter base if you can omit the first step, and just close upward.

Comment: @AlexKruckman - thanks! I'll revert to (a slightly modified form of) my original wording, then.

Comment: Thank you for linking me to the errata, I looked around briefly for a page like this but wasn't able to find it.